# Issue using TF Text with Tensorflow serving

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a model with TF Text preprocessing included in the graph exported for Tensorflow Serving but I have the following error :

```
2019-06-28 13:29:19.048482: E tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:37] Loading servable: {name: my_model version: 1561728496} failed: Not found: Op type not registered 'UnicodeScriptTokenizeWithOffsets' in binary running on 57085cb71277. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

It seems that the 'UnicodeScriptTokenizeWithOffsets' Op from TF Text is not included in TF Server. I saw that a solution could be to build a custom serving image to include TF Text Ops and Kernel using Tensorflow docker development image, is it right ? How could I do that ? Or Maybe there is a simpler solution ?

I'm using :

- Tensorflow 2.0.0b0
- Tensorflow Text 1.0.0b0

Serving is done with the official docker image from : tensorflow/serving:latest

Thanks,

Maxime

Comment: Tensorflow Serving 2.2.0rco supports TF text ops now. Can you please try using it. For more info pleas take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1490)